# “Essential C++”ch3.9 use "back_inserter(ivec2)" replace the "ivec2.begin()" can't compile

Tags: c++

This example copy from the book:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;

template<typename input_iterator_tag, typename output_iterator_tag,
typename elem_type, typename comp>
output_iterator_tag
filter(input_iterator_tag first, output_iterator_tag last,
output_iterator_tag at, const elem_type &val, comp pred)
{
    while ((first = find_if(first, last, bind2nd(pred, val))) != last)
    {
        cout << "found value: " << *first << endl;
        *at++ = *first++;
    }
    return at;
 }

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
const int elem_size = 8;
int ia[elem_size] = { 12, 8, 43, 0, 6, 21, 3, 7 };
vector<int>ivec(ia, ia + elem_size);

int ia2[elem_size];
vector<int>ivec2(elem_size);

cout << "filtering integer array for values less than 8\n";
filter(ia, ia + elem_size, ia2, elem_size, less<int>());
cout << "filtering integer vector for value greater than 8\n";
filter(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), ivec2.begin(), elem_size, greater<int>  ());//it's work ok
filter(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), back_inserter(ivec2), elem_size, greater<int>());//compile error,no instance of function template "filter" matches 

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Why i use "back_inserter(ivec2)" replace " ivec2.begin()" as the book said, but it can't compile in the visual studio;

```
   IntelliSense: no instance of function template "filter" matches the argument list argument types are: (std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>, const int, std::greater<int>)
```

anyone can help me correct it and why?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typo in the function declaration. The second parameter (`last`) should be a `input_iterator_tag` not an `output_iterator_tag`, as it should match the `first` iterator since it is compared directly to `first`.

```
template<typename input_iterator_tag, typename output_iterator_tag,
typename elem_type, typename comp>
output_iterator_tag
filter(input_iterator_tag first, input_iterator_tag last,
output_iterator_tag at, const elem_type &val, comp pred)
```

Note: The reason it worked for your first case was that the both input and output types were the same.

Comment: That's also a terrible way to name a template parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much.any advice for name template parameter?